# functions and validating values

Tags: php, function, if-statement, include

I'm working on having `PHP` validate negative values, numeric and non numeric and empty values in a value.

I need php to display error message if a value is negative, empty, non-numeric.

I'm also having an issue with not getting values from my `HTML` form in `$_POST`.

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
$operation = $_POST['operation'];
```

and in my form the names of each value is correctly spelled for negative values i have

```
if ($first || $second < 0) {
    print("<h2> Error one or more inputs are not negative numbers</h2>");
     echo("<a href="calculator.html"></a>");
}
```

For empty numbers I have:

```
if (empty($first) || empty($second) == true) {
    print("<p> One or more input field is empty </p>");
    echo("<a href="calculator.html"></a>");
}
```

and for a value that is not numeric:

```
if (!is_numeric($first) || !is_numeric($second) == false) {
    print("<h2> Error one or more inputs are not numbers</h2>");
    echo("<a href="calculator.html"></a>");
}
```

My issue is that every time any number is entered i get error messages if its `true` or `false`.

Comment: *"my issue is that every time any number is entered i get error messages if its true or false"* - Being what exactly?

Comment: `if ($first or $second < 0)` < that isn't valid. You need to break those up into 2 separate statements.

Comment: Your `!is_numeric ... == false` is a double negative. Why are you using that?

Comment: You need to apply the condition to each value you are testing e.g. `if ($first < 0 || $second < 0)` and you don't need to compare boolean values so just write `if (empty($first) || empty($second))` and `if (!is_numeric($first) || !is_numeric($second))`. note the logical or operator in PHP is `||`

Comment: nick what i used is the or operator to see if anyone of them was empty or  negative or a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change this condition, because PHP will understand it as `($first || $second) <0` where `$first || $second` will be evaluated as single boolean statement, and than the boolean value returned will be casted to int (true -> 1, false -> 0) and than checked with the `<0`, and it will be always false, so the code should be changed to:

```php
if ($first<0 or $second < 0)
{
   print("<h2> Error one or more inputs are not negative numbers</h2>");
   echo("<a href="calculator.html"></a>");
}
```

in this block instead, the  `== true` is useless, because `if this or that` in php means "check the first value and see with the proper cast to boolean, is true or false, and than apply the `or` between this two value", and in this case the "this" and "that" are already boolean value, so it's totally useless, but if you want to explicit it, code should look like `empty($first) == true  or empty($second) == true` else you are expliciting only one of the twos, or better take it out and so the code should looks like

```php
if (empty($first) or empty($second))
{
   print("<p> One or more input field is empty </p>");
   echo("<a href="calculator.html"></a>");
}
```

And in the last block of code, the logic is wrong, because you want to check if one of the two value are not numeric, so `!is_numeric($value)` will return true if the value is not numeric, and false if it was numeric, so it the code should be changed to

```php
if (!is_numeric($first) or !is_numeric($second))
{
 print("<h2> Error one or more inputs are not numbers</h2>");
 echo("<a href="calculator.html"></a>");
}
```

Also, in my opinion, i would suggest you to use `||` instead of `or` . and `&&` instead of `and`, because most of the other languages use that operator, and so once you've learned, you're okay with all the languages

About not been able to fetch data from the request, please post in the answer the form and i'll edit this answer with a possible solution

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202495/discussion-on-answer-by-albertosinigaglia-functions-and-validating-values).